# JBoss 6 is not recognizing the Datasource name in persistence.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, jboss, datasource

My operating system is Window 7. I am working on Eclipse Kepler 64-bit. The JDK is 1.6.0_34. The Database Server is SQL Server 2008 R2. The Application Server is JBoss 6.1.0.Final.

I have a database "MyDB" on the Database Server.

I copied the jTDS 1.2.6 JDBC Driver (`jtds-1.2.6.jar`) to the `JBOSS_HOME\server\default\lib` folder.

I then create a datasource with the name as **jdbc/MyDB** (`jtds-ds.xml` file in `JBOSS_HOME\server\default\deploy` folder which is hitting "MyDB" database using jTDS JDBC Driver. This is the `jtds-ds.xml` file:

```
<datasources>
  <local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>jdbc/MyDB</jndi-name>
    <connection-url>jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://MY-PC:1433/MyDB;tds=8.0;lastupdatecount=true</connection-url>
    <driver-class>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
    <user-name>dbo</user-name>
    <password>password1</password>
    <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1</check-valid-connection-sql>      
  </local-tx-datasource>    
</datasources>
```

I then run the JBoss and check the log file to see if datasource is ok and JBoss was ok with it.

> 22:22:25,574 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound
>   ConnectionManager
>   'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=jdbc/MyDB' to JNDI
>   name 'java:jdbc/MyDB'

Now in Eclipse, I create a Dynamic Web Project; the Target Runtime is "JBoss 6.x Runtime"; the Dynamic Web Module is "2.5" and the JPA is "2.0". I name that project as ***MyWebProject***.

I define 1 persistence unit with name ***MyPU***; and I defined the JTA DataSource name as **jdbc/MyDB**. This is the `persistence.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="MyPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/MyFinanceDB</jta-data-source>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Now I deploy my app to JBoss and then start the JBoss. And JBoss gives me this error message:

> 22:22:26,394 ERROR
>   [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] Error
>   installing to Start:
>   name=persistence.unit:unitName=MyWebProject.war#MyPU
>   state=Create: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc not bound  at
>   org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:771)
>   [:5.0.5.Final]    at
>   org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:779)
>   [:5.0.5.Final]    at
>   org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getObject(NamingServer.java:785)
>   [:5.0.5.Final]    at
>   org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:396)
>   [:5.0.5.Final]    at
>   org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:728)
>   [:5.0.5.Final]    at
>   org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:688)
>   [:5.0.5.Final]    at
>   javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
>   [:1.6.0_34]   at
>   org.jboss.jpa.impl.deployment.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:120)
>   [:2.0.0]  at
>   org.jboss.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitDeployment.start(PersistenceUnitDeployment.java:252)
>   [:1.0.2-alpha-4]  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   [:1.6.0_34]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   [:1.6.0_34]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   [:1.6.0_34]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>   [:1.6.0_34]   at
>   org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:60)
>   [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.1.SP1]     at
>   org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:168)
>   [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.1.SP1]     at
>   org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66)
>   [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.1.SP1]     at
>   org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction$JoinpointDispatchWrapper.execute(KernelControllerContextAction.java:257)
>   [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ExecutionWrapper.execute(ExecutionWrapper.java:47)
>   [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchExecutionWrapper(KernelControllerContextAction.java:125)
>   [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchJoinPoint(KernelControllerContextAction.java:72)
>   [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.LifecycleAction.installActionInternal(LifecycleAction.java:202)
>   [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54)
>   [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42)
>   [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:894)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:641)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:182)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:58)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:63)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1571)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679)
>   [:2.2.2.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106)
>   [:6.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143)
>   [:0.2.2]  at
>   org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151)
>   [:0.2.2]  at
>   org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94)
>   [:0.2.2]  at
>   org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54)
>   [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42)
>   [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654)
>   [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]  at
>   org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190)
>   [:0.2.2]  at
>   org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87)
>   [:0.2.2]  at
>   org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215)
>   [:0.2.2]  at
>   org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159)
>   [:0.2.2]  at
>   org.jboss.profileservice.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:154)
>   [:0.2.2]  at
>   org.jboss.system.tools.ProfileServiceToolsFacade.addURI(ProfileServiceToolsFacade.java:233)
>   [:6.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.system.tools.LegacyDeploymentScannerAdapter.addURL(LegacyDeploymentScannerAdapter.java:140)
>   [:6.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.system.tools.DeploymentScanner.addURL(DeploymentScanner.java:91)
>   [:6.1.0.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.system.tools.DeploymentScanner.addURL(DeploymentScanner.java:83)
>   [:6.1.0.Final]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) [:1.6.0_34]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   [:1.6.0_34]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   [:1.6.0_34]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>   [:1.6.0_34]   at
>   org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
>   [:6.0.0.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
>   [:6.0.0.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88) [:6.0.0.GA]
>     at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:271)
>   [:6.0.0.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:670)
>   [:6.0.0.GA]   at
>   org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerWrapper.invoke(MBeanServerWrapper.java:138)
>   [:6.1.0.Final]    at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1427)
>   [:1.6.0_34]   at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$200(RMIConnectionImpl.java:72)
>   [:1.6.0_34]   at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1265)
>   [:1.6.0_34]   at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1360)
>   [:1.6.0_34]   at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:788)
>   [:1.6.0_34]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) [:1.6.0_34]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   [:1.6.0_34]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   [:1.6.0_34]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>   [:1.6.0_34]   at
>   sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:303)
>   [:1.6.0_34]   at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
>   [:1.6.0_34]   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method) [:1.6.0_34]   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
>   [:1.6.0_34]   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
>   [:1.6.0_34]   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
>   [:1.6.0_34]   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
>   [:1.6.0_34]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>   [:1.6.0_34]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>   [:1.6.0_34]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_34]

Why JBoss is not recognizing the DataSource **jdbc/MyDB** defined inside `persistence.xml` when it already has bound this DataSource?

Am I missing any configuration file for JBoss?

Comment: it doesn't seems to me a correct datasource declaration, why not define it as `java:/MyFinanceDB` and then use the same name on `persistence.xml` ?